# How can I configure an Azure Function running **locally** to use Azure B2C to perform the authentication?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure Function that is configured to authenticate users using Azure B2C. Everything work as expected.

[image: Azure AD configured]

However I am not finding a way to make it work when I run the function locally. When running in Azure, the Function is called with the `ClaimsPrincipal` instance filled with proper claims regarding the user.

```
[FunctionName("get-accounts")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(
        AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
        "get",
        Route = "v1/accounts"
    )]
    HttpRequest httpRequest,
    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    //
}
```

When running locally, the `ClaimsPrincipal` instance has no claims associated to the user.

**Question**

When I am debugging, how can I configure an Azure Function **running locally** to use Azure B2C to perform the authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAD is an IDM (Identity Management Service), which maintains users' identities. Now when you create an application in your dev machine and want users of AAD to login there, in that case, the user first needs to be authenticated by AAD. But then the question comes, get authenticated for what? The answer to that is to get authenticated for your App. Now does AAD know your app till now. The answer is no, AAD has no clue about your app. Hence to make AAD aware of you app, you need to register your App using the App Registration Portal (in case of OAuth Apps). Once the registration is done, AAD is aware of your app and hence when a request comes from this app to get a user authenticated, AAD trusts your app and hence would get the user authenticated for your app and send an access token back for your app to consume and know that the user is authenticated. This is how your app gets protected by AAD, irrespective of the platform it is hosted on (whether on Azure App Service Platform or on your on-prem WebServer).

You can follow this to implement B2C for your funcion :
https://sundarcloud.com/2020/06/05/azure-ad-b2c-token-validation-using-azure-functions/

You may also check the following for better understanding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent